# Python curses program. What char is ^?

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping, curses, python-curses

I've got a program using curses with python3. When the user hits backspace I try to catch it like so:

```
elif (ch == curses.KEY_BACKSPACE or
      ch == 8): #8 is ASCII backspace, appears in terminal as ^H if not handled
    ...
```

But now my cygwin terminal is sending `^?` when I type backspace. I'm familiar with `^A` equals ASCII 1, `^B` equals ASCII 2 etc, But what character is `^?`, and how can I catch it using curses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"^?" is the [DEL character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character), \x7f.

Comment: So its like ASCII -1 (127 in unsigned 7-bit) because `?` is two chars before `A`. That makes sense.

Comment: Here's the wikipedia page on caret notation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29

I think I tried searching for 'carat' and was unsuccessful.